# How to add custom Icons to NativeBase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have the `.ttf` and `.svg` files for customized icons that I designed. But I would like to import them into my NativeBase project, making them available for use in NB's `<Icon />` component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing up an answer now.

Comment: @Yossi there, I wrote the answer. It's what worked for me. Give me an up-vote if it works for you! good luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### React Native Custom Icon Font for NativeBase

Adopted from:
https://medium.com/@kelleyannerose/react-native-custom-icon-font-with-no-sad-red-screen-72b8d09a0e7b

This is what worked for me :)

---

**Step 0:**
React Native Vector Icons install and link
Make sure you have react-native-vector-icons installed and linked. If you haven’t installed it yet, follow install instructions from their docs. Usually these two commands should do it for you.

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
react-native link
```

---

**Step 1:** Add icons in Fontello
First, you have to get your icons into a font. Go to [fontello.com](http://fontello.com), and as their UI so accurately suggests, ‘Drag custom SVG icons or SVG font here’.

[image]

---

**Step 2:** Select icons
This might not be as obvious, but after you upload the icons, you have to select which you want to include (one by one). This is nice because you can choose icons from other libraries if you want to and they’ll all be a part of your one icon font. You’ll see your selections clearly with a red circle.

[image]

---

**STEP 3 / BIG TIP:** NAME YOUR FONT
I recommend naming your font in the little box next to the big red button in Fontello. This way there won’t be any questions what your font name is. And the file name will match the font name, so you can use the same name in iOS and Android leaving less room for error — phew.

[image]

---

**Step 4:** Download webfont
Click the red ‘Download webfont’ button in top right. You can get the config file on its own by clicking the down arrow, but you’ll need the .ttf file as well.

[image]

---

**Step 5:** Add .ttf file to project
Find the `.ttf` file in the fonts directory from your download and add it somewhere in your `src` file that makes sense. I usually have a `src/assets/fonts` directory that I use. I like to have this file accessible somewhere in a shared file for my own sanity.

---

**Step 6 (iOS):** Add .ttf to Resources in Xcode
Open the project in Xcode `ios/yourprojectname.xcodeproj`. Once in Xcode, right click on the resources directory, select ‘Add files to “yourprojectname”…’ and select the custom icon font .ttf file (I have mine available in that `src/assets/fonts` directory I mention in step 5).

---

**Step 7 (iOS):** ADD FONT TO COPY BUNDLE RESOURCES
While still in Xcode, go to ‘Build Phases’ in the top bar, open ‘Copy Bundle Resources’ and you’ll see a list of the icon fonts from react-native-vector-icons. Check for your icon font name in that list, if it’s not there, click the ‘+’ and select your .ttf file.

[image]

---

**Step 8 (iOS)**: ADD TO INFO.PLIST
Open your info.plist file (preferably before you add any additional targets, because this is the info.plist that will get copied) and open ‘Fonts provided by application. Click the little circled ‘+’. It’ll add a line at the top for you to type in your font file name.

[image]

---

**Step 9 (Android):** Add `.ttf` to Android
Add the `.ttf` file to the `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` directory. This should already exist because you’ve already installed `react-native-vector-icons` and run `react-native link` which places all it’s icon font files here for Android.

---

**Step 10:** Add configuration and the icon component to your project
Back to the shared `src` directory! Add two files somewhere in your shared `src` directory called `icon-font.js` and `icon-font.json` or whatever you want to call them. I like to have a `src/config` directory for (you guessed it) configuration stuff.

Go back to the files you downloaded from Fontello, grab the `config.json` contents and paste them into your `icon-font.json` file.

Open your `icon-font.js` file and paste the following (replacing `kelleyicons` with whatever you named your custom icon font of course).

```
import { createIconSetFromFontello } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import fontelloConfig from './icon-font.json';
const MyIcon = createIconSetFromFontello(fontelloConfig, 'kelleyicons');
export default MyIcon;
```

---

**Step 11:** Add instance
Before running the app, go ahead and add an instance of your icon font somewhere so you can double check it’s working right off the bat. In any of your component or screen files, import your icon from the `icon-font.js` file.

```
import MyIcon from './../config/icon-font.js';
```

And in your view somewhere, use it like so (becasue I'm using NativeBase I wrapped the custom Icon in NativeBase's `Icon` component). You can find the individual names to use in the `icon-font.json` file.

```
<Icon><MyIcon
  name={'chrome'}
  size={20}
  color={'#333333'} /></Icon>
```

---

**Step 12:** Save, run and (hopefully) celebrate!
Make sure everything is saved up, go to your terminal, `run npm start`, open your app, and cross your fingers for zero errors!

---

**BONUS TIP!**

As of React Native 0.60 resources are automatically linked. This means that if you run `pod install` (which you eventually will) you *may* see an error saying `'Multiple commands produce' error when building with new Xcode build system'`. If you are running the `New Build System` `(File > Workplace Settings > Build System)`. This error is because React Native is trying to link the same resources twice. If this happens to you, simply go back to **Step 7 (iOS): ADD FONT TO COPY BUNDLE RESOURCES** select all the .ttf files and press the `-` button to remove. Then build again :)

Comment: I use your solution but nothing to show and placeholder remove.

Answer (score 2):

### React Native Custom Icon for NativeBase

NativeBase provides you with `createIcon`, which you can use to create and export your own icons, individually, using the `viewBox` and the path data of your `.svg` files.

#### One path

If your icon only has one path data, you can supply it as such :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createIcon } from 'native-base';

export const MyCustomIcon = createIcon({
  viewBox: '0 0 512 512',
  d: 'M424.337,272.548c-72.91,...,8.532v16.549H271.514z',
});
```

#### Multiple paths

Using `Path` and `G` from `react-native-svg`, you can supply the said paths to  the path property in `createIcon` parameters.

Here is an example :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createIcon } from 'native-base';
import { Path, G } from 'react-native-svg';

export const MyCustomIcon = createIcon({
  viewBox: '0 0 512 512',
  path: <G>
    <Path d="M486.4,0H25.6C11.468,...,8.533V486.4z" />
    <Path d="M452.267,...,8.533V452.267z" />
  </G>
});
```

#### Bonus

You can even use `useToken` to give your custom icon the colors of your theme

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createIcon, useToken } from 'native-base';
import { Path, G } from 'react-native-svg';

export const MyCustomIcon = (props) => {
  const [white, primary, secondary] = useToken('colors', ['white', 'primary.400', 'secondary.400']);

  const component = createIcon({
    viewBox: '0 0 370 370',
    path: <G>
      <Path fill={primary} d="M350.00159,370.00153h-230a20,...,8.533V452.267z" />
      <Path fill={white} d="M250.00159,40.00154h-230a20,...,40Z" />
      <Path fill={secondary} d="M135.1,219.84,36.41,...,338.57l39.49-56.66Z" />
    </G>,
    ...props
  });

  return component.type.render();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We do something like below to show .ttf and .svg icons in React

```
  import ttfFile from “./fonts/fileName.ttf”;
  import svgFile from “./svg/fileName.svg”

  <img src={ttfFile} />
  <img src={svgFile} />
```

Or

```
 <img src={require(“./fonts/fileName.ttf”)}/>
  <img src={require(“./svg/fileName.svg”)} />
```

Excuse me for wrong double quotes typo because I am answering from my mobile