# Add custom icons in Expo

Tags: react-native, icons, expo, native-base

I am using the native base library and i want to add a custom Icon i made. I found some answers like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583461/how-to-add-custom-icons-to-nativebase),  but all answers are for react native and i have to export my files from Expo to edit the android and ios folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways to create a custom icon in `Expo`. I'll tell you one of them. See the rest of the **official documents**.

Returns your own custom font based on the `glyphMap` where the key is the icon name and the value is either a UTF-8 character or it's character code. `fontFamily` is the name of the font NOT the `filename`. The `expoAssetId` can be anything that you can pass in to `Font.loadAsync`. See `react-native-vector-icons` for more details.

**Example**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { createIconSet } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const glyphMap = { 'icon-name': 1234, test: '∆' };
const expoAssetId = require("assets/fonts/custom-icon-font.ttf");
const CustomIcon = createIconSet(glyphMap, 'FontName', expoAssetId);

export default class CustomIconExample extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <CustomIcon name="icon-name" size={32} color="red" />
    );
  }
}
```

Useful Links: 
[Documents for the Custom Icon](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/)

Comment: so say you wish to add antd icon library to expo, do you use your method described above? for antd they use 'type' prop instead of 'name' prop, would that also work with additional props?

Comment: Requiring the font to get the `expoAssetId` is what fixed things for me.