# custom Icons in NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to use my own icon group in native-base.i read this post [How to add custom Icons to NativeBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583461/how-to-add-custom-icons-to-nativebase?answertab=active#tab-top)

bu nothing to show. this is my code I want to use, in first `Item` after added icon placeholder remove:

```
<View style={styles.view}>
            <Item floatingLabel style={{ width: w / 1.9, height: w / 7, borderColor: '#507783', marginBottom: 0, }} >
              <Icon><MyIcon name="ico_user" style={{ color: "#fff" }}/></Icon>
              <Input returnKeyType='next' autoCapitalize="none" onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)} style={{ paddingBottom: 0, color: '#fff', textAlign: 'left', fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile', fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 8, }} placeholderTextColor="#507783" placeholder='نام کاربری' />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel secureTextEntry={true} style={{ width: w / 1.9, height: w / 7, borderColor: '#507783' }} >
              <Icon type="Fontisto" name="locked" fontSize={25} style={{ color: "#fff" }} />
              <Input returnKeyType='next' autoCapitalize="none" onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)} style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'left', fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile', fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 8, }} placeholderTextColor="#507783" placeholder='رمز عبور' />
            </Item>
            <Button block style={{ width: w / 1.9, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#59c5b9', marginTop: 56 }} onPress={() => internet.isConnected ? _goLogin() : Alert.alert('لطفا اتصال به اینترنت خود را بررسی نمایید')}>
              <Text style={styles.btntext}>ورود</Text>
            </Button>

          </View>
```

and this is my `icon-fon.js`:

```
import {createIconSetFromFontello} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import fontelloConfig from './ecfco.json';
const Icon = createIconSetFromFontello(fontelloConfig,'ecfco');
export default Icon;
```

and i check this directory in android:`android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` font correctly added.
and check ios version evry think is ok but not working.
and native-base version : `"native-base": "^2.13.12",`

UPDATE: 
 when using `MyIcon` outside of `Item` work perfectly but when used an icon for `Input` nothing to show
thank for helping solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. read this post on gihub : [Trying to add an Image on the right of a Label. It's working fine with stackedlabel but floating label is making the image](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2271)
change my way, replace `Icon` to `Thumbnail` and correct code below:

```
<Item floatingLabel >
              <Thumbnail square source={require('../../assets/Newimage/Login/ico_user.png')} resizeMode='center' />
              <Label>نام کاربری</Label>
              <Input returnKeyType='next' autoCapitalize="none" onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)}  />
 </Item>
```